# instantiate $scope in module with multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**How do I instantiate $scope for an angularjs module that has multiple controllers?**  Currently, I am getting the following error message:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module hello due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module navigation due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module $scope due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module '$scope' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

The structure of the app is as follows:

The `hello` module is defined as:

```
'use strict';
/** * Main module of the application. */
angular
.module('hello', ['ngAnimate', 'ngRoute', 'ngTouch', 'auth', 'home',      
                    'secure', 'public1', 'navigation', 'ui.bootstrap' ])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
    //a bunch of config stuff like routeProvider, etc.
})
.run(['$cookies', function($cookies) {
    //some startup stuff like setting default values for cookies, etc.
}]);
```

`navigation.js` is defined as:

```
'use strict';
angular
.module('navigation', ['$scope', 'auth', 'modalService', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('navigation', function($scope, auth, modalService, $route, $uibModal) {
    // code for various stuff, 
    //  including code calling the second controller below
    $scope.someVariable = 'some value';
});

// Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.
angular.module('navigation', ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', 'items'])
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {  
    //code that is controlled by code from the preceding controller
    $scope.someOtherVariable = 'some other value'; 
});
```

Note that, when i remove `$scope` from the injection arrays as per comments below, I get the following error at the two lines `$scope.someVariable = 'some value'` and `$scope.someOtherVariable = 'some other value'`:

```
'$scope' is not defined.
```

Comment: Only angular `module`'s can only be injected inside DI array while bootstrapping app..you are injecting $scope dependency which isn't possible..$scope only available inside controller and directive link function

Comment: you cannot inject $scope as it is not a dependency.$scope is given by angular so that it can be used within controller.

Comment: @PankajParkar  Ok, so then how do I alter the code in the OP to get it to work?  I just want to experiment with the code from a sample so that I can move it around into other configurations.

Comment: removing $scope from array should do it

Comment: @MKoosej But `$scope` is used in both controllers.

Comment: as @Rishab777 said $scope is a variable that angular will add it for you , it's not a dependency that you should tell angular to add to your controller. Hope that makes it clear

Comment: @MKoosej I added something to the OP showing how `$scope` is used, and how it throws an `undefined` error when it is not manually injected.  So to recap, there is a failure to inject error when it is manually injected, and there is an `undefined` error when it is not manually injected.  What gives?

Answer (score 1):

There's two concepts here that you are mixing up. Declaring the list of dependencies for your angular module(app) and injecting them to your controller or factory.

Declaring dependency with your module is done using:

```
angular.module('myMoudle', ['anotherModule', 'andAnotherModule'])
```

While injecting them to your controller or factory is done in controller/factory function:

```
myModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'anotherModule', function($scope, anotherModule) {});
```

Note here myModule is already defined and there's no reason to redefine it .you can also access your already defined module using this syntax:

```
angular.module('myModule', []).controller(...)
```

A more advance way of injecting dependency modules is using $inject.
You can find more info about Angular DI [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: Thank you for replying.  For the purposes of clarity.  Can you please use the module and controller names from the OP?  That would enable me to actually test your suggestion.

Comment: I'll test it in a working environment and send a fiddle

Comment: OK.  One aspect is how the `navigation` controller can see the `modalInstanceCtrl`.  I am noodling with it also on my devbox.

Comment: You don't pass controllers to each other. It's against angular pattern. You should define a service or directive for that.

Comment: The code came from the plnkr that you can view by clicking on this link, scrolling to the bottom of the modal section, and clicking on the plnkr link:  https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: The only difference from the official example in my link is that I am trying to add it to a module that is one of a number of modules in an app.  So that the navigation module has two controllers instead of just one.

Comment: You should define the controller when you want to add the modal functionality to your html and add it as ng-controller. I'm not sure what you're trying to do but you can usually do it by adding a function to your scope like the example in the link.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes initializing your controllers:

This code:

```
angular.module('navigation', ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', 'items'])
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items){  
    //code that is controlled by code from the preceding controller
});
```

Should be rewritten in the following way:

```
angular.module('navigation', [])
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', [ '$scope', '$uibModalInstance, 'items',
    function($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) { // go with your code here
}]);
```

So basically you have to move all your injections related to controller out from module instantiation and set it into controller one.

Comment: Nope.  **This does not answer the question.**  See the stuff that I added to the OP stating that `$scope is not defined.`